# What could cause a Safari extension (toolbar button) to not trigger when Safari sends the "command" event?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, safari-extension

I am working on a toolbar button for Safari 6 and I even have the button in my toolbar. I have a Global.html with all the code. It has an event listener like so:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", functionName, false);
```

The function contains this:

```
function functionName(event) {
    console.log(event.command);
    <!-- more code here -->
}
```

But that console.log is never triggered. Nothing happens at all when I press the button. I have looked at code for other extensions and I cannot find any issues with mine. When I inspect my Global.html, I get a ReferenceError saying that the variable 'safari' can't be found (in the first code snippet).

Am I missing something that is needed to make a button like this work? This is my first JS/extension project and I am unsure of how to debug.

Comment: Are you opening your global.html in a tab, as if it were a web page? Else I can't imagine why `safari` would be undefined.

Comment: @canisbos I actually figured it out. I wasn't inspecting it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update: Don't open Global.html as a webpage. Use the Inspect Global Page button in Extension Builder.